# Create live mulitbootable flash drive with linux and windows7

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, partitioning, grub

So recently I have been having some trouble with my laptop, been getting bsod...

So I thought, instead of carrying my external around with me and risking it becoming damaged, why not create a flashdrive which runs grub when booted to, then gives me the option to boot and install windows or boot into a live linux "cd"

I am not sure if this has been done before,so advice would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) should work for you, just run it and select  the windows installer and your chosen distro(I'd recommend Debian so you can set up persistence easily).